# how to update values from .6 to 0.6 for all records in a table

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In my case I have to update all the records which starts  with point to zero point eg: .6  to 0.6  in one go can it be done using regex in plsql

Comment: what datatype is the column u are trying to update, varchar2?

Comment: yes the data type is varchar 2

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? You'd rather modify column datatype.

Comment: it is string like eg: your total value is .6

Comment: You can check out your derived query whether works for the cases where value of the column starts with **.** and **digit** such as **`.678`**

Answer (score 0):

Could you post some examples? For such a sample data set, it kind of *works* ...

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (col)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'Your total value is .6' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'This costs .25 USD' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'What about 23.5?' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'Total sales are .7 and .5' FROM DUAL
 11         UNION ALL
 12         SELECT 'Totals are 0.2 and .34 thankyou.' FROM DUAL)
 13  SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE (col, ' \.', ' 0.') result
 14    FROM test;

COL                              RESULT
-------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Your total value is .6           Your total value is 0.6
This costs .25 USD               This costs 0.25 USD
What about 23.5?                 What about 23.5?
Total sales are .7 and .5        Total sales are 0.7 and 0.5
Totals are 0.2 and .34 thankyou. Totals are 0.2 and 0.34 thankyou.

SQL>
```

Comment: Will it work for the given example: 'total sales are .7 and .5'

Comment: it won't work for `.6` either

Comment: See edited answer, Ravindra (added example from your comment). It still works.

Comment: one more issue eg:  ' I have added .7 and .5 thankyou.' in this example at last i'm ending the string with .(dot) and it should not get updated, is there any solution for this

Comment: That's still OK (see edited answer).

Comment: it wont give u 0 bcs in front of the .(dot) must be ' '(space) and that ' '(space) becomes 0 if there is a letter and a dot like in your example (thankyou.) it wont add a 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` with **`'([.\d])'`** pattern to be replace with **`'0.'`** such as

```sql
WITH t(col) AS
(
 SELECT 'your total value is .. .6 .66 .76'     FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'your total value is .. 0.6 .16  0.761' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'your total value is .6 .66 .76'        FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT '.6'                                    FROM dual 
)
SELECT REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'\.(\d)','0.\1'),'00.','0.') AS new_col
  FROM t
```

| NEW_COL |
| --- |
| your total value is .. 0.6 0.66 0.76 |
| your total value is .. 0.6 0.16 0.761 |
| your total value is 0.6 0.66 0.76 |
| 0.6 |

where an extra `REPLACE()` function is used considering the cases some decimal numbers with **`0.`** might already exist

**<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b821a538d44ac5306b6f2dd9b2b96c2e)</kbd>**